# Unable to make outlets

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, interface-builder, iboutletcollection

I'm not able to create an outlet on the view controller.

I started out with the single view application template, and added another view controller to my storyboard. Now, when I try to create an outlet from the second view controller to the file, Xcode doesn't allow me to make it.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you change the class of this second view controller to a new custom class?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a View Controller on a story board you have to change it's class to the View Controller you want it to be controlled by, you can do it by opening the Identity Inspector tab in the Utilities panel (option+command+3) and type or find the class name of the View Controller you want, after doing this, you can play with it's outlets, check out the screenshot:

[image]

EDIT: Forgot to mention, you have to have selected the View Controller you want to change the class for in the left list.